# E-mail with images and Array not being Sent

Tags: php, forms

Good Evening (Here in Brazil, at least),

I Have a form with some checkbox and file input for images, but when I Submit it, nothing happens.

What could be wrong?

Form:

```
    <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="envia_email.php">
           <fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="nome" id="nome">Nome Completo</label>
                <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" style="width: 10em" value="" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="width: 13em" value="" />
        </div>
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="email">Local</label>
                <input type="text" id="local" name="local" style="width: 13em" value="" />
            </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
            <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" style="width: 13em"  value="" />
        </div>
               <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="whatsapp" VALUE="Whatsapp"> Whatsapp <br><br>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="idade">Idade</label>
            <input type="text" id="Idade" name="idade" style="width: 3em"  value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="cache">Cachê</label>
            <input type="text" id="cache" name="cache" style="width: 10em"  value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="cache">Atendimento</label>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="atendimento[]" VALUE="Hotéis e Motéis"> Hotéis e Motéis <br><br>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="atendimento[]" VALUE="Residência"> Residência <br><br>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="atendimento[]" VALUE="Local Próprio"> Local Próprio <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="cache">Atendo</label>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="atendo[]" VALUE="Homens"> Homens <br><br>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="atendo[]" VALUE="Mulheres"> Mulheres <br><br>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="atendo[]" VALUE="Casais"> Casais <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="cache">Formas de pagamento</label>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="pagamento[]" VALUE="Dinheiro"> Dinheiro <br><br>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="pagamento[]" VALUE="Cheque"> Cheque <br><br>
            <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="pagamento[]" VALUE="Cartão"> Cartão <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="mensagem">Atendimento e serviços</label>
            <textarea rows="6" style="width: 15em" id="mensagem" name="mensagem"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 1</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em" />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 2</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 3</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 4</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div> 
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 5</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 6</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 7</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="img">Imagem 8</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" style="width: 10em"  />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="enviar">Enviar</button>

     </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $local = $_POST['local'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $whatspapp = $_POST['whatsapp'];
    $idade = $_POST['idade'];
    $cache = $_POST['cache'];
    $atendimento = $_POST['atendimento'];
    $atendo = $_POST['atendo'];
    $pagamento = $_POST['pagamento'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $imagem = $_FILES['imagem'];

    $para = "email@email.com";


    $bound  = "XYZ-". date('dmYis') ."-ZYX";

    $texto = "--$bound\n";
    $texto .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n";
    $texto .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\n\n";
    $texto .= "<b>Nome: </b>". $nome ."</br>";
    $texto .= "<b>E-mail: </b>". $email ."</br>";
    $texto .= "<b>Local: </b>". $local ."</br>";
    if($whatsapp != '') {
        $texto .= "<b>Whatsapp:</b> Sim</br>";
    };
    $texto .= "<b>Idade: </b>". $idade ."</br>";
    $texto .= "<b>Cachê: </b>". $cache ."</br>";
    foreach($atendimento as $Atendimento)   {
        $texto .= $Atendimento .", ";
    };
    $texto .= "</br>";
    foreach($atendo as $Atendo) {
        $texto .= $Atendo .", ";
    };
    $texto .= "</br>";
    foreach($pagamento as $Pagamento)   {
        $texto .= $Pagamento .", ";
    };
    $texto .= "</br>";
    $texto .= "<b>Mensagem: </b>". $mensagem ."</br>";
    $txt1 = "email@email.com";
    $texto .= "--$bound\n";
    foreach($imagem as $Imagem) {
        if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name'])) and !empty($Imagem)    {
            $fp = fopen($Imagem['tmp_name'],"rb");
            $anexo = fread($fp,filesize($Imagem['tmp_name']));
            $anexo = base64_encode($anexo);
            fclose($fp);
            $anexo = chunk_split($anexo);

        $texto .= "Content-Type: ".$Imagem["type"]."\n"; 
        $texto .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$Imagem["name"]."\"\n";
        $texto .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"; 
        $texto .= "$anexo\n";
        };
    };
    $texto .= "--$bound--\r\n";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: \"$nome\" <$email>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Bcc: {$txt1}\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound\"\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "$bound\n";

    mail($para,"Contato Anuncio",$texto,$headers);

?>
```

I Asked some friends and they all told it's okay, but still not working. Help!

Regards.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Dekel as i wrote, When I submit, nothing happens. Probally my PHP is the bad guy here...

Comment: You aren't outputting anything on this page. `echo`, `print`, or leave the PHP and output something. Also enable error reporting and check your logs.

Comment: when you say "nothing happens" it means that something **should** happen. What should happen?

Comment: @Dekel it should send an email with the form informations. I'm using the mail() php function in the last line of my php file.

Comment: So change your question, because you are asking about email that is not being sent, not about form and images...

Comment: if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name'])) and !empty($Imagem) what is and means

Comment: @Dekel Post edited.

Comment: If you remove all the images the email getting sent successfully?

Comment: @KiranMuralee It verify if the file input is empty. If it is, skip this array record, else, it attach the file.

Comment: it should be like  if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name']) && !empty($Imagem) )

Comment: you have written the code as  if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name'])) and !empty($Imagem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one problem I find in your PHP code.You have written

```
if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name'])) and !empty($Imagem) {
```

But it should be like

```
if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name']) && !empty($Imagem))    {
```

or

```
if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name']) and !empty($Imagem))    {
```

Another problem I found in your php code is that you have used

```
$whatspapp = $_POST['whatsapp'];
```

But in another place you used like `if($whatsapp != '') {`

Try debugging for more errors

Comment: Hey! It almost worked fully. Just the attachment didn't worked. Any idea why?

Comment: No I want the live post data to see if file data actually get sent to server

Comment: Also verify the  codes from  foreach($imagem as $Imagem) {
        if(file_exists($Imagem['tmp_name'])) and !empty($Imagem)    {
            .... as these code deal with your attachment

Comment: @GabrielSilva you could check in browser console or use xdebug to get the post datas in action to verify everything is sent correctly from client side.

Comment: I uploaded here: http://samfbas.com.br/teste/anuncio.html You can test it

Comment: I have seen another mistake in your code  $whatspapp = $_POST['whatsapp']; but you have used $whatsapp

Comment: i've seen this almost now! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127339/discussion-between-kiran-muralee-and-gabriel-silva).